# FirstPersonCharacterCotroller doesn't work as he should

Tags: c#, sprite, frame-rate

Ich bin neu in Unity und habe auch die neuste Version 2021.1.3f1 und will in Zukunft ein FPS Shooter machen.
In meinem Projekt kann man sich schohn mit der Maus umschauen aber das Movement funktioniert nicht so ganz,weil ich mich bewegen kann, aber die Steuerung passt sich nicht der Kamera an.Kann mir da jemand helfen ,Bitte.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public CharacterController controller;

        public float speed = 12f;

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {
            float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

            controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post your questions in English as this is the English Stackoverflow website.